# No url in the adress bar for Ajax.ActionLink calls

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

when I click this link:

Ajax.ActionLink("Get customers","GetCustomers","Customer");

my url bar still shows: www.mysite.com and not ww.mysite.com/Customer/GetCustomers

how can I change that?

Comment: you can use fragments to keep track of ajax history, like tabs, this also solves back btn with ajax

Answer (score 0):

The web-page is loaded via ajax in the background and you are not doing a redirect the URL will therefore not change.

Do a redirect to action rather.

Comment: yes... but when I do my whole site with jquery ajax how can this be seo + user friendly concerning the url ?